# How to add a local variable to pymongo.find if it's not None?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-requests, pymongo

I run a web service with an api function which uses a method I created to interact with MongoDB, using pymongo.

The json data comes with post may or may not include a field: `firm`. I don't want to create a new method for posts that does not include a `firm` field.

So I want to use that `firm` in `pymongo.find` if it does exists, or I want to just skip it if it doesn't. **How can I do this with using one api function and one pymongo method?**

**API function:**

```py
@app.route(f'/{API_PREFIX}/wordcloud', methods=['POST'])
def generate_wc():
    request_ = request.get_json()
    firm = request_.get("firm").lower()
    source = request_["source"]
    since = datetime.strptime(request_["since"], "%Y-%m-%d")
    until = datetime.strptime(request_["until"], "%Y-%m-%d")

    items = mongo.get_tweets(firm, since, until)

    ...
```

**The pymongo method:**

```py
def get_tweets(self, firm: str, since: datetime, until: datetime):
    tweets = self.DB.tweets.find(
        {
            # use firm here if it exists (I mean not None), else just get items by date
            'date': {'$gte': since, '$lte': until}
        })
    ...
```

Here in the second code, comment line in `find`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it involves two different queries: `{date: ...}` and `{date: ..., firm: ...}` depending on the existence of `firm` in the input, you would have to check if `firm` is not `None` in `get_tweets` and execute the proper query.

For example:

```
def get_tweets(self, since, until, firm=None):
    query = { 'date': { '$gte': since, '$lte': until } }
    if firm is not None:
        query['firm'] = firm
    tweets = self.DB.tweets.find(query)
    ....
```

Note that since `firm` has a default value, it needs to be last in the `get_tweets` parameter list.

Comment: That's actually seems nice, there can be a base query and more fields can be added depending some conditions. I will try it asap, thanks.